# Can I convert a stringified JSON array back to a BigQuery strucutre?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to take a STRING field that contains a nested JSON structure from a table called `my_old_table`, extract a nested array called "alerts" from it, then insert it into a column in a new table called `my_new_table`.  The new column is defined as:

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<cuid STRING, title STRING, created TIMESTAMP>>
```

I'm using this SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_dataset.my_table(
   id, alerts)
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(extra, "$.alerts") AS content_alerts
FROM my_dataset.my_old_table
```

This gives me:

```
Query column 2 has type STRING which cannot be inserted into column content_alerts, which has type ARRAY<STRUCT<cuid STRING, title STRING, created TIMESTAMP>> at [4:1]
```

I don't see a way of parsing the extracted string this back to a structure....  Is there another way to do this?

*Edit:*

The original value is a json *string* that looks like this:

```json
{
  "id": "bar123",
  "value": "Test",
  "title": "Test",
  "alerts": [
    {
      "id": "abc123",
      "title": "Foo",
      "created": "2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "abc124",
      "title": "Accepting/Denying Claims",
      "created": "2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract `$.alerts` and insert it into the `ARRAY<STRUCT<cuid STRING, title STRING, created TIMESTAMP>>` somehow.

*Edit #2*

To clarify, this reproduces the issue:

```sql
CREATE TABLE insights.my_table
(
  id string,
  alerts ARRAY<STRUCT<cuid STRING, title STRING, created TIMESTAMP>>
);

CREATE TABLE insights.my_old_table
(
   id string,
   field STRING
);

INSERT INTO insights.my_old_table(id, field)
VALUES("1", "{\"id\": \"bar123\",\"value\": \"Test\",\"title\": \"Test\",\"alerts\":[{\"id\": \"abc123\",\"title\": \"Foo\",\"created\": \"2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z\"},{\"id\": \"abc124\",\"title\": \"Accepting/Denying Claims\",\"created\": \"2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z\"}]}");
```

Based on the above setup, I don't know how to extract "alerts" from the *STRING* field and insert it into the STRUCT field.  I thought I could add a JSON PARSE step in there but I don't see any BigQuery feature for that.  Or else there would be a way to manipulate JSON as a STRUCT but I don't see that either.  As a result, this is as close as I could get:

```sql
INSERT INTO insights.my_table(id, alerts)
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(field, "$.alerts") AS alerts FROM insights.my_old_table
```

I'm sure there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: can you show us the content of `JSON_EXTRACT(extra, "$.alerts")`?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I added a data example, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION JsonToItems(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(input).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
"""; 
)
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(extra, "$.id") AS id,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(alert, "$.id") AS cuid,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(alert, "$.title") AS title,
      TIMESTAMP(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(alert, "$.created")) AS created
    FROM UNNEST(JsonToItems(JSON_EXTRACT(extra, "$.alerts"))) alert 
  ) AS alerts,
FROM `project.dataset.my_old_table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION JsonToItems(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(input).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
"""; 
WITH `project.dataset.my_old_table` AS (
  SELECT '''
{
  "id": "bar123",
  "value": "Test",
  "title": "Test",
  "alerts": [
    {
      "id": "abc123",
      "title": "Foo",
      "created": "2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "abc124",
      "title": "Accepting/Denying Claims",
      "created": "2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z"
    }
  ]
}
''' extra
)
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(extra, "$.id") AS id,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(alert, "$.id") AS cuid,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(alert, "$.title") AS title,
      TIMESTAMP(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(alert, "$.created")) AS created
    FROM UNNEST(JsonToItems(JSON_EXTRACT(extra, "$.alerts"))) alert 
  ) AS alerts,
FROM `project.dataset.my_old_table`
```

with result

[image]

Obviously, you can then use this in your `INSERT INTO my_dataset.my_table` statement

Comment: Thanks---this gets me most of the way there.  The key seems to be dropping to JavaScript for the json parsing steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the extracted string back to a BigQuery structure like so:

```
SELECT STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<cuid STRING, title STRING, created TIMESTAMP>>
[('Rick', 'Scientist', '2020-01-17')]) FROM my_dataset.my_old_table;
```

### I just tried it with your data

I have inserted your data in a BigQuery table:

```
INSERT INTO dataset.table
  VALUES('{"id": "bar123", "value": "Test", "title": "Test", "alerts":
 [{ "id": "abc123", "title": "Foo", "created": "2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z"},
 {"id": "abc124", "title": "Accepting/Denying Claims", "created": "2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z"}]}');
```

and queried it, converting it back to a BigQuery structure:

```
SELECT STRUCT<cuid STRING, title STRING, created TIMESTAMP>("abc123",
 "Foo", "2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z"),("abc124", "Accepting/Denying 
 Claims", "2020-01-17T23:18:59.769908Z") FROM blabla.testingjson;
```

Output:

```
Row | f0_.cuid | f0_.title | f0_.created 
----------------------------------------
1   | abc123   | Foo       | 2020-01-17 23:18:59.769908 UTC
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  My value is a string literal, but your example uses a struct literal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to demonstrate there.  I've added code to reproduce the issue into the question.